# Get the name of the method that called another method

Tags: php

### The goal

Get the name of a method that called another method.

### The problem

I need to get a method name in another method, and now I'm using this:

```
$crazyDinosaur = new CrazyDinosaur(300, 600);
$crazyDinosaur->attack(new NinjaCat(), __FUNCTION__);
```

How can I discover that `CrazyDinosaur` attacked `NinjaCat` without the `__FUNCTION__`? Is it possible?

### More details

What I exactly want is: `x` triggers an event. I don't want to say again that `x` triggered the event, because the event should know who's triggering itself.

Comment: $crazyDinosaur->attack(new NinjaCat(), $crazyDinosaur); ???

Comment: In general your code is the easiest way.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php it might help you.

Comment: Isn't there a way to discover whose attacked the NinjaCat inside of the `attack`'s method?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally have an abstract `Actor` or `Character` class, sub-class them, and then create instances of the sub-classes. For example:

```
<?php
abstract class Actor {}

abstract class Animal extends Actor {}

class Dinosaur extends Animal {}
```

Classes, as you know, can have properties. So one property could be `$type`, which holds a string representation of the class. So if you had created an instance of `Dinosaur`, `$type` could simply be `dinosaur`.

So now we have:

```
<?php
abstract class Animal extends Actor
{
    protected $type;
}    

class Dinosaur extends Animal
{
    protected $type = 'dinosaur';

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    protected $type = 'cat';
}

$crazyDinosaur = new Dinosaur();
$crazyCat = new Cat();
```

I think your problem is you’ve attached the `attack()` method to the wrong class; I would attached it to the victim’s class. So if dinosaur is attacking cat, then I’d call the `attack()` method on the cat class, and pass your dinosaur object as a parameter. That way, you know what’s attacking what by just inspecting what type of class the `$attacker` is.

```
<?php
class Cat extends Animal
{
    public function attack(Actor $attacker)
    {
        // code here to do things like deduct cat's health etc.
    }
}

$crazyDinosaur = new Dinosaur();
$crazyCat = new Cat();

$crazyCat->attack($crazyDinosaur);
```

You can extend your `attack` method to accept additional parameters. For example, the strength of the attack to change the amount of damage it does to the victim.

I’d also suggest looking into the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), as that’s ideal in this case. Also, PHP isn’t an event-driven language so isn’t the best fit for a game.

Comment: Your sentence `$crazyCat->attack($crazyDinosaur);` sounds very strange. But I get your point of view. Hang on a second to try by myself.

Comment: *And this isn't a game, lol...* Actually, is an ErrorHandler. When an error happens, I need to know where it is happening. The context that I pass to the Stack Overflow is easier to understand and the scenario is *almost* the same.

Comment: You really shouldn’t change the context of questions, as otherwise I would have pointed you to the [debug_backtrace()](http://de3.php.net/debug-backtrace) function instead of writing a convoluted answer based on a game.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
class creature{

public $attack_strength;
public $health ;

public function attack($enemy){
  $damage = $this->attack_strength;
  $enemy->health -= $damage;
  log_event($this->name . " attacked " . $enemy->name . " making " . $demage . " points of damage");
}
}

class NinjaCat extends creature{

}

class crazyDinosaur extends creature{

}
```

Comment: Your logic is good and we are almost there. But what I exactly want is: `x` triggers an event. I don't want to say again that `x` triggered the event, because the event should know who's triggering itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`get_class($this)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
...
function attack($victim)
{
  $attacker = get_class($this);
  var_dump($attacker);
}
...
```

Comment: Negative. I want to "pass" the class/method/function name just triggering an method. Example: `$say->hi();` and in `hi()`'s method I discover that `$say` is the trigger.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135959/get-variable-name-of-object-inside-the-object-php