# How to get name of a initializer variable inside a class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I would like to know, if it is possible in PHP (using reflection or not) to get the variable name `abc` inside the class method in this example.

```
class Example
{
   public function someMethod()
   {
     // once this method is called, I want it to echo `abc` in this example
   }

}
```

Now, when I call the method using a variable name like

```
$abc= (new Example)->someMethod(); 
echo $abc;  // abc
```

I would like to see the name of the variable, 'foo' shown, in other words the class would have to be aware of the variable name, when returning the methods contents.

Comment: You want the object to be aware of the name of the variable its assigned to?

Comment: And what do you expect to be echoed if you do `$abc = (new Example)->someMethod(); $def = &$abc;
echo $def;` or even `$abc = (new Example)->someMethod(); $def = &$abc; unset($abc);
echo $def;`

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What would it echo if it were `$abc = array($example->someMethod())`?

Comment: @Barmar It would echo `abc` Actually, it *is* [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135959/get-variable-name-of-object-inside-the-object-php/19136281#19136281) just wanted to know if there was an easier way.

Comment: I don't know, but it is possible to do it, I just wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to find the name inside the object. It does seem hard to describe though

Comment: @castis exactly, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135959/get-variable-name-of-object-inside-the-object-php/19136281#19136281) but looking to have more examples

Comment: You say you want to see the variable name **foo** shown but there's no mention of `foo` before. So what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you give a use case?

Comment: @fejese modified. Obviously, it would be impossible to show `foo` without the object being instantiated. sorry for the blunder

Comment: So why not just returning it? You do `return 'foo';` in the method. Again, with a bit more meaningful, full example it might be easier to understand what you need.

Comment: lol, because I could call the method from many variable names, not just `$foo`. What if I did `$bar`? I would have to modify the return value too. I guess you had not understood the question clearly.

Comment: How about passing the chosen name as an argument?

Comment: @Contax I think there's a flaw in your design - the class shouldn't care about the name of a variable that you're storing it in, why would it and why would it affect the logic of the class? If it's that crucial to your logic, pass it in as an argument and code the variable name using variable variables to keep it DRY.

Comment: @scrowler Actually, this 'hack' is supposed to make my app DRY compliant massively. So, that is not the problem. I could pass it as argument, but it does seem very backward, considering the language is good enough to do it on it's own, why resort yo 1-level PHP tricks as opposed to using the language to it's best level

Comment: I fail to see how this would ever make your app more DRY... and why wold you care what the variable is that an object instance is assigned to from within the instance... that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think you should give a feasible and real example of what you want. Your question plus the discussion here on comments does not make one understand what you need, so it will be difficult to help.

Comment: @prodigitalson Trust me. It does help a lot. I could show it to you, but it is not worth the time. But, it does help. I guess, it all depends on what you are building, and how you are building it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It is not important to what I need to apply this too, I just nee a basic answer that works with the code I have provided above.

Comment: just another variant added for your question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135959/get-variable-name-of-object-inside-the-object-php/27852534#27852534  just FYI :-)

Comment: @Contax there is taking DRY too far sometimes too though :-) using a reflection class if it worked would be a bigger overhead that passing in the name

Answer (score 1):

I always pass in the name of the variable it will be assigned to if it it is required

```
class myclass {
    var $myname;
   function __construct($myname='no name') {
       $this->myname=$myname;
    #print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
   }

  function sayHello()
    {
    return "hello from " . $this->myname . "\n";
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$myVar = new myclass("myVar");
$yourVar = new myclass("yourVar");

echo $myVar->sayHello();
echo $yourVar->sayHello();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just what a 1-level PHP developer would do. If you seen in my question, I am asking for possible answer involving [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) if I wanted to pass it as argument, it would have been too easy.

Comment: I thought php was for 1-level programmers.  I mean a square wheel will work but ...

Comment: @SoyF.Elmono Maybe. But you can't compare people who use only PHP as one could be expert and the other could be a beginner. I am neither, so this answer seemed to noob for me

Comment: Seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135959/get-variable-name-of-object-inside-the-object-php  - is how they do it too. Perhaps not so noob?